# Bootstrap carousel fixed position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, fixed

I want to make my bootstrap carousel slider to stay fixed on the top, so when I scroll down, I want the content below to cover the carousel slider and not the carousel to move up along with the other content. It's a normal Bootstrap Carousel slider.

```
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-ex">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
    <img src="pics/cheese_and_biscuits.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2>Djathi Shajshet!</h2>
    <p>Djathi paragraf</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
    <img src="pics/cheese.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2>Djathi Shajshet!</h2>
    <p>Djathi paragraf</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
    <img src="pics/cheeseboard.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2>Djathi Shajshet!</h2>
    <p>Djathi paragraf</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#carousel-ex" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a> <a href="#carousel-ex" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a></div> </div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

Comment: Add code so people can help

Comment: Dude, always give some codes, whatever you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, hope it fulfill your requirement.

**CSS CODE**

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { 
     min-height: 1500px;
    }

    .carousel{
      position: fixed;
    }

   #myContents { 
       position: relative; 
       padding: 550px; /* your carousel image size + 30px */ 
       z-index: -1;
   }
</style>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
    ........
     <!-- put carousel remaining code here -->
    ........
</div> <!-- #myCarousel ends -->

<div id="myContents" class="row">
    ....
    <!-- put all remaining contents here -->
    ....
</div> <!-- #myContents ends -->
```

**NOTE**: If you want contents scroll over the carousel, then make **z-index positive.**

Comment: thnx for the answer @SHAZ. first i'll explain why i didnt provide u with the code. i mentioned it that its a default bootstrap carousel slider, so i think u know the the html and css is provided by the bootstrap framework by default. btw i tried position:fixed; but when change the position to "fixed" i loose the content below the carousel and only the navbar and the carousel is what i see. anyways ill post the code below ...

Comment: @user3795503, if answer fulfill your requirements, so please **accept** and **upvote** answer. So it help others.

Comment: I know you mentioned default bootstrap, but what i  **mentioned** is, show some codes " **whatever you tried** "

Comment: ok @SHAZ i edited my question above and added the code. unfortunately ur answer didnt help. i tried 'position: fixed;' before i came here. it didnt work so i decided to ask for a solution here. thnx. any other idea ?

Comment: yes @SHAZ it stays fixed, but as i mentioned above, i loose all the other content of the site and all i see is the slider and the navbar (after i change the possition to fixed).

Comment: now i realised that all the content goes behind the slider. so how do i bring the other content back to top and leave the slider behind.

Comment: @user3795503, i clearly indicated in notes if you want contents over carousel then make **z-index** value positive.